# In Surprise package for recommender systems, how to print out the recommended movies for a given user?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, recommendation-engine

For many algorithms for example SVD, the ready built-in functions are:

1. `predictions = algo.fit(trainset).test(testset)`
   -- which prints the predicted rating score for the test set (so for movies that users have already given the ratings)
2. `predictions = algo.predict(uid, iid)`
   -- predict the rating score of the iid of uid

But how can I print the `top N` recommended movie for a user (even though this user has not yet seen/given rating for some movies). I have tried: `"algo.fit(trainset).test(data)"` but it gives me error?

I have tried also using KNN in surprise to print `k nearest neighbors` of a user 
In the surprise package example, it has the u.item file, but if I want to use my own data (one table that has uid, iid, and rating), how can I compute the `"raw id"` of an user and an item?

Answer (score 4):

This code snippet is shared [from Surprise Documentation FAQ](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/FAQ.html) and may be helpful.

```
from collections import defaultdict

from surprise import SVD
from surprise import Dataset


def get_top_n(predictions, n=10):
    """Return the top-N recommendation for each user from a set of predictions.

    Args:
        predictions(list of Prediction objects): The list of predictions, as
            returned by the test method of an algorithm.
        n(int): The number of recommendation to output for each user. Default
            is 10.

    Returns:
    A dict where keys are user (raw) ids and values are lists of tuples:
        [(raw item id, rating estimation), ...] of size n.
    """

    # First map the predictions to each user.
    top_n = defaultdict(list)
    for uid, iid, true_r, est, _ in predictions:
        top_n[uid].append((iid, est))

    # Then sort the predictions for each user and retrieve the k highest ones.
    for uid, user_ratings in top_n.items():
        user_ratings.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        top_n[uid] = user_ratings[:n]

    return top_n


# First train an SVD algorithm on the movielens dataset.
data = Dataset.load_builtin('ml-100k')
trainset = data.build_full_trainset()
algo = SVD()
algo.fit(trainset)

# Than predict ratings for all pairs (u, i) that are NOT in the training set.
testset = trainset.build_anti_testset()
predictions = algo.test(testset)

top_n = get_top_n(predictions, n=10)

# Print the recommended items for each user
for uid, user_ratings in top_n.items():
    print(uid, [iid for (iid, _) in user_ratings])
```